# How to receive and parse a QByteArray over UDP into a structure of bit fields?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, udp

There are 2 structures of bit fields combined into one structure. Previously, when the total size of the structure allowed, it did union through union in uint64. Now the size of the structures has become larger, I pass it to QByteArray from the server to the client and now there is a problem with receiving and parsing.

How do normal people do it right? You can still with an example, I will be glad!

Client side

```
QDataStream stmFrom( &buffer, QIODevice::ReadWrite );

QTextStream cdl( & log );
for(int i(0); i < 5; i++)
{
    stru m;// union in it is a structure with bit fields and uint64
    stmFrom >> m.all; // from QByteArray to uint64
    cdl << m.all;// write to file
    cdl << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Step 1) Reassemble the `QByteArray` into a `uint64_t` (taking care of endianness issues, if any) 2) Read bits from the reassembled `uint64_t` as before.

Comment: Your approach seems fine, as long as you keep the sending and receiving sides in sync. If your structure grows larger or you need to start nesting structures, consider evolving to protocol buffers or flatbuffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is obscure and low-level solution to me. As far as i have learned low-level solutions generally harder to maintain, read and debug.

Serialization/deserialization has been implemented lots of times by many developers/communities. I think it is better to use one of the common, well-known and bug-free serialization libraries.

For example, https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal is a decent option, just let it serialize and deserialize for you or just use QDataStream.

To prevent conflicts between host and client machines endianness, you should use `portable_archive` or `QDataStream`.

Also if you are using UDP and your data is important, you should add checksum part due to the loss chance on UDP.

If you are using TCP it is required to add length of the message to the message due to its stream oriented structure.

**Example** I am demonstrating basic, ugly but higher level implementation

```
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

template< int MsgId , typename T>
struct msg
{
    int id() { return msg_id; }
    T data;

private:

    template< int Id , typename Type >
    friend QDataStream& operator<<( QDataStream& out , const msg<Id , Type>& );

    template< int Id , typename Type >
    friend QDataStream& operator>>( QDataStream& out , msg<Id , Type>& );
    int msg_id { MsgId };
};

template< int MsgId , typename T>
QDataStream& operator <<( QDataStream& out , const msg< MsgId , T >& m )
{
    return out << m.msg_id << m.data;
}

template< int MsgId, typename T>
QDataStream& operator >>( QDataStream& in , msg< MsgId , T >& m )
{
    return in >> m.msg_id >> m.data;
}

struct server_status
{
    int number_of_active_users {};
    int station_load {};
};

QDataStream& operator <<( QDataStream& out , const server_status& s )
{
    return out << s.station_load << s.number_of_active_users;
}

QDataStream& operator >>( QDataStream& in , server_status& s )
{
    return in >> s.station_load >> s.number_of_active_users;
}

struct error_occurred
{
    int code;
    QString msg;
};

QDataStream& operator <<( QDataStream& out , const error_occurred& e )
{
    return out << e.code << e.msg;
}

QDataStream& operator >>( QDataStream& in , error_occurred& e )
{
    return in >> e.code >> e.msg;
}

int main( int argc , char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication a { argc , argv };

    // Serialize to byte array
    QByteArray msg_buffer;
    QDataStream out { &msg_buffer , QIODevice::WriteOnly };

    msg<10 , server_status> m;
    m.data.station_load = 54;
    m.data.number_of_active_users = 112;

    out << m;

    msg<11 , error_occurred> e;
    e.data.msg = "Device temperature is so high.";
    e.data.code = 401;

    out << e;

    // Send over udp
    // some_udp_socket->write( msg_buffer );

    auto incomed_datagram = msg_buffer; // some_udp_socket->receiveDatagram().data();

    QDataStream in { &incomed_datagram , QIODevice::ReadOnly };

    while( !in.atEnd() )
    {
        int msg_id {};

        in >> msg_id;

        if ( msg_id == 10  )
        {
            server_status s;
            in >> s;
            qDebug() << "station_load : %" << s.station_load << "active_users :" << s.number_of_active_users;
        }
        else if ( msg_id == 11 )
        {
            error_occurred e;
            in >> e;
            qDebug() << "code :" << e.code << "msg :" << e.msg;
        }
    }

    a.exec();
}
```

message_id is checking and corresponding class is initialized manually but it is possible to write a template class which dispatchs and initializes the messages according to message_id's automatically.